# Excel VBA Data Validation Dropdown, current highlighted item

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, dropdown

Short question:
Is there any way to tell which item is highlighted in a Data Validation cell drop down?

Details:
I'm trying to make a tooltip (using a form that follows the mouse when that cell is moused over; will have to change this to cover the dropdown area as well) that gives more information based on the current selection.
I want to do this for the current highlighted item in the list, so that the user can get more info without having to select the item then start over if it's not the one they want.

I also am trying to avoid using the Form Controls & ActiveX Controls. That's more by request from the person in charge than my decision.

Comment: If you have code, best to [edit] your question with it.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, I don't have any code relevant to the question.